# Hat Polykite Shape

Tags: graphics, regions

How can I create the [hat polykite](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HatPolykite.html) shape, also known as the "[einstein](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.10798.pdf)" in mathematics?

[image]

Comment: For tilings also look at the Wolfram Function Repository function: [HatHexagons](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/HatHexagons/)

Comment: See numerous related discussions: [hat-1](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2856178), [hat-2](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2858759), [hat-3](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2957268), [hat-4](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2958428), [hat-5](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2916247)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"HatPolykite"` is also available in [`LaminaData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaminaData.html):

```
hatpolykite = LaminaData["HatPolykite"];

hatpolykite["Diagram"]
```

[image]

The property `"BoundaryMeshRegion"` returns a function that gives a `BoundaryMeshRegion` as a function of `a`:

```
hatpolykite["BoundaryMeshRegion"]
```

[image]

For `a = 1`

```
hatpolykite["BoundaryMeshRegion"][1]
```

[image]

Similarly for the property `"Vertices"`:

```
vertices = hatpolykite["Vertices"][1]
```

[image]

```
Show[hatpolykite["BoundaryMeshRegion"][1], 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize@Large, Point /@ vertices}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This interesting topic can be exposed form various points of view allowing to have a better grasp of the subject. Rewriting vertices cyclically

```
vrts = {{{-1, -Sqrt[3]}, {1, -Sqrt[3]}, {3/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {3, -Sqrt[3]}, 
        {9/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {4, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, Sqrt[3]}, {3/2, (3 Sqrt[3])/2},
        {1, Sqrt[3]}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {0, 0}, {-(3/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {-1, -Sqrt[3]}}};
```

we can plot the hat polykite without external information simply with

```
Graphics[ Line[vrts]]
```

We can elucidate several symmetries of the hat polykite on the various lattices of circles with different radii. First with a lattice of circles of radius $1$:

```
Graphics[{Thick, 
  Circle @@@ {{{0, 0}, 1}, {{2, 0}, 1}, {{1, Sqrt[3]}, 1}, {{4, 0}, 1},
    {{3, -Sqrt[3]}, 1}, {{3, Sqrt[3]}, 1}, {{-1, -Sqrt[3]}, 1},
    {{1, -Sqrt[3]}, 1}}, Red, Line[vrts]}]
```

[image]

or a denser lattice with more circles

```
Graphics[{Darker @ Magenta, 
  Circle @@@ {{{0, 0}, 1}, {{2, 0}, 1}, {{1, Sqrt[3]}, 1}, {{4, 0}, 1},
    {{3, -Sqrt[3]}, 1}, {{3, Sqrt[3]}, 1}, {{-1, -Sqrt[3]}, 1}, {{1,-Sqrt[3]}, 1}},
  Darker @ Cyan, 
  Circle @@@ {{{2, Sqrt[3]}, 1}, {{2, -Sqrt[3]}, 1}, {{1, 0}, 1}, 
    {{3, 0}, 1}, {{0, -Sqrt[3]}, 1}, {{0, Sqrt[3]}, 1}, {{-1, 0}, 1},
    {{-2, -Sqrt[3]}, 1}, {{4, -Sqrt[3]}, 1}}, 
  Darker @ Blue, Thickness[0.005], Line[vrts]}]
```

[image]

We need not restrict to circles of radius $1$, here we have circles of radii $2$ and $\sqrt{3}$:

```
Graphics[{Darker @ Magenta, 
  Circle @@@ {{{1, Sqrt[3]}, 2}, {{3, Sqrt[3]}, 2}, {{1, -Sqrt[3]}, 2},
    {{3, -Sqrt[3]}, 2}}, 
  Darker @ Cyan, 
  Circle @@@ {{{-(3/2), Sqrt[3]/2}, Sqrt[3]}, {{3/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, Sqrt[3]},
    {{3/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, Sqrt[3]}, {{-(3/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, Sqrt[3]}, 
    {{9/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, Sqrt[3]}, {{9/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, Sqrt[3]}},
  Darker @ Blue, Thickness[0.005], Line[vrts]}]
```

[image]

$6$ vertices lie on any cyan circle of one or more hat polykites on the tiling of the plane.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
reg = Entity["Lamina", "HatPolykite"]["BoundaryDiagram"] // 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics
```

[image]

The polygon coordinates are:

```
MeshPrimitives[reg, 0] /. Point[a_] :> a
```

Comment: Where did you get the word `Lamina` from?

Comment: It showed up when I started the query with `=`  sign and entered `hat polykite`.

Comment: To guess that word would take me much more time than figuring out coordinates of the shape by hand. I think more appropriate world would be `Tile`.

Comment: No need to guess anything, that's why there is Free-Form Input. For `"hat polykite"`, it [returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmcEy.png) `Entity["Lamina", "HatPolykite"]`.

Comment: But to associate word `HatPolykite` with `Lamina` seems to be inappropriate. The more people use this Free-form with that word the more will the AI (or algorithm or whatever it is) "think" that is the right association. And when you type `Tile, HatPolykite` it will output nothing.

Comment: It works correctly with `"HatPolykite tile"`. Also, read the description for _lamina_ at the [MathWorld (Polygon)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polygon.html), paragraph _"While the "filled" usage ..."_. Lastly, I don't think the users' usage of the word matters here; these polygons are simply stored under the `Lamina` entity in the Wolfram Language.

Comment: ...but incorrectly with `tile HatPolykite`

Answer (score 3):

- Use the lattice to directly draw the polygon( we start from `{0,0}`).

```
basis = {e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6} = CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 6];
lattice = 
  Tuples[{Range[0, 5], Range[0, 4], Range[0, 2], Range[0, 1], 
     Range[0, 1], Range[0, 1]}] . basis;
pts = FoldList[
   Plus, {0, 0}, {e1 + e1, e2, e1 + e6, e1 + e2, e3, e4, e3 + e2, 
    e3 + e4, e5, e4, e6 + e5, e5 + e4, e6}];
Graphics[{LightYellow, Polygon@pts, Green, AbsolutePointSize[5], 
  Arrow@Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1], Brown, Point /@ lattice}, 
 Axes -> True, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

[image]

- Using transformation to show the structure of such region (the link in the comment of @Vitaliy Kaurov)
  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2856178

```
Clear[e1, e2, lattice, five, polys];
{e1, e2} = {AngleVector[0], AngleVector[π/3]};
lattice = Table[{i, j} . {e1, e2}, {i, -4, 4}, {j, -3, 4}];
five = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, -1}, {2, -2}, {3, -1}, {2, 0}} . {e1, e2}];
polys = {five, 
   TransformedRegion[five, 
    RotationTransform[π, {0, -1} . {e1, e2}]], 
   TransformedRegion[five, 
    RotationTransform[(2 π)/3, {0, 0} . {e1, e2}]], 
   TransformedRegion[five, 
    ReflectionTransform[RotationTransform[π/2]@e2, {0, 0}]]};
Graphics[{{RandomColor[], #} & /@ polys, Point /@ lattice}]
```

[image]

```
reg = RegionUnion[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics /@ polys];
Graphics[{LightYellow, reg, Green, 
  MeshPrimitives[reg, 1] /. Line -> Arrow}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's also easy to represent as an `AnglePath`

```
path = With[{t1 = 60 °, t2 = 90 °, r = Sqrt[3]},
   AnglePath[{{1, 0}, {1, t1}, {r, -t2}, {r, -t1}, {1, t2},
              {1, -t1}, {r, -t2}, {r, -t1}, {1, t2},
              {2, -t1}, {1, -t1}, {r, -t2}, {r, t1}}]];

Graphics[Line[path], AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]
```